# Is protect_against_forgery required in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf, csrf-protection

I have been reading on Rails security for hours now and I am a bit puzzled about the CSRF mechanism. It is stated everywhere I look that in order to switch it on you need to use the `protect_against_forgery` function.

I am working in a big application (Rails3.2-4) and can't seem to find any use of it in the codebase. Still the CSRF mechanism seems to be on:

```
protect_against_forgery? # true
```

What's the official answer from Rails on the matter? Do we need to set it explicitly or is it automatically set?

Answer (score 0):

In the application.html.erb , we have `csrf_meta_tags` that are used to prevent the forgery request, if you have removed that tags , then you will get **Invalid token authenticity** error.
It is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, forgery protection is on by default. Should be enabled somewhere in your ApplicationController. Possibly in form of `before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` or something like that.